# Implementing Eigenface on OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-detection

I am trying to implement the eigenface algorithm using OpenCV in VS2010. I am using this site as a reference: http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_5/index.html

I am facing some problems in implementing it and I have few questions on it.

I have already configured the VS2010 to include all the libraries.

The code is here:

// recognize.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include "cvaux.h"
#include "highgui.h"


//// Global variables
IplImage ** faceImgArr        = 0; // array of face images
CvMat    *  personNumTruthMat = 0; // array of person numbers
int nTrainFaces               = 0; // the number of training images
int nEigens                   = 0; // the number of eigenvalues
IplImage * pAvgTrainImg       = 0; // the average image
IplImage ** eigenVectArr      = 0; // eigenvectors
CvMat * eigenValMat           = 0; // eigenvalues
CvMat * projectedTrainFaceMat = 0; // projected training faces


//// Function prototypes
void learn();
void recognize();
void doPCA();
void storeTrainingData();
int  loadTrainingData(CvMat ** pTrainPersonNumMat);
int  findNearestNeighbor(float * projectedTestFace);
int  loadFaceImgArray(char * filename);
void printUsage();


//////////////////////////////////
// main()
//
void main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    char c;
    // validate that an input was specified
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printUsage();
        return;
    }

    if( !strcmp(argv[1], "train") ) learn();
    else if( !strcmp(argv[1], "test") ) recognize();
    else
    {
        printf("Unknown command: %s\n", argv[1]);
        printUsage();
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////
// learn()
//
void learn()
{
    int i, offset;

    // load training data
    nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/OpenCV/train.txt");
    if( nTrainFaces < 2 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Need 2 or more training faces\n"
                "Input file contains only %d\n", nTrainFaces);
        return;
    }

    // do PCA on the training faces
    doPCA();

    // project the training images onto the PCA subspace
    projectedTrainFaceMat = cvCreateMat( nTrainFaces, nEigens, CV_32FC1 );
    offset = projectedTrainFaceMat->step / sizeof(float);
    for(i=0; i<nTrainFaces; i++)
    {
        //int offset = i * nEigens;
        cvEigenDecomposite(
            faceImgArr[i],
            nEigens,
            eigenVectArr,
            0, 0,
            pAvgTrainImg,
            //projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl + i*nEigens);
            projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl + i*offset);
    }

    // store the recognition data as an xml file
    storeTrainingData();
}


//////////////////////////////////
// recognize()
//
void recognize()
{
    int i, nTestFaces  = 0;         // the number of test images
    CvMat * trainPersonNumMat = 0;  // the person numbers during training
    float * projectedTestFace = 0;

    // load test images and ground truth for person number
    nTestFaces = loadFaceImgArray("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/OpenCV/test.txt");
    printf("%d test faces loaded\n", nTestFaces);

    // load the saved training data
    if( !loadTrainingData( &trainPersonNumMat ) ) return;

    // project the test images onto the PCA subspace
    projectedTestFace = (float *)cvAlloc( nEigens*sizeof(float) );
    for(i=0; i<nTestFaces; i++)
    {
        int iNearest, nearest, truth;

        // project the test image onto the PCA subspace
        cvEigenDecomposite(
            faceImgArr[i],
            nEigens,
            eigenVectArr,
            0, 0,
            pAvgTrainImg,
            projectedTestFace);

        iNearest = findNearestNeighbor(projectedTestFace);
        truth    = personNumTruthMat->data.i[i];
        nearest  = trainPersonNumMat->data.i[iNearest];

        printf("nearest = %d, Truth = %d\n", nearest, truth);
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////
// loadTrainingData()
//
int loadTrainingData(CvMat ** pTrainPersonNumMat)
{
    CvFileStorage * fileStorage;
    int i;

    // create a file-storage interface
    fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/OpenCV/facedata.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
    if( !fileStorage )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open facedata.xml\n");
        return 0;
    }

    nEigens = cvReadIntByName(fileStorage, 0, "nEigens", 0);
    nTrainFaces = cvReadIntByName(fileStorage, 0, "nTrainFaces", 0);
    *pTrainPersonNumMat = (CvMat *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "trainPersonNumMat", 0);
    eigenValMat  = (CvMat *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "eigenValMat", 0);
    projectedTrainFaceMat = (CvMat *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "projectedTrainFaceMat", 0);
    pAvgTrainImg = (IplImage *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "avgTrainImg", 0);
    eigenVectArr = (IplImage **)cvAlloc(nTrainFaces*sizeof(IplImage *));
    for(i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
    {
        char varname[200];
        sprintf_s( varname, "eigenVect_%d", i );
        eigenVectArr[i] = (IplImage *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, varname, 0);
    }

    // release the file-storage interface
    cvReleaseFileStorage( &fileStorage );

    return 1;
}


//////////////////////////////////
// storeTrainingData()
//
void storeTrainingData()
{
    CvFileStorage * fileStorage;
    int i;

    // create a file-storage interface
    fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/OpenCV/facedata.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );

    // store all the data
    cvWriteInt( fileStorage, "nEigens", nEigens );
    cvWriteInt( fileStorage, "nTrainFaces", nTrainFaces );
    cvWrite(fileStorage, "trainPersonNumMat", personNumTruthMat, cvAttrList(0,0));
    cvWrite(fileStorage, "eigenValMat", eigenValMat, cvAttrList(0,0));
    cvWrite(fileStorage, "projectedTrainFaceMat", projectedTrainFaceMat, cvAttrList(0,0));
    cvWrite(fileStorage, "avgTrainImg", pAvgTrainImg, cvAttrList(0,0));
    for(i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
    {
        char varname[200];
        sprintf( varname, "eigenVect_%d", i );
        cvWrite(fileStorage, varname, eigenVectArr[i], cvAttrList(0,0));
    }

    // release the file-storage interface
    cvReleaseFileStorage( &fileStorage );
}


//////////////////////////////////
// findNearestNeighbor()
//
int findNearestNeighbor(float * projectedTestFace)
{
    //double leastDistSq = 1e12;
    double leastDistSq = DBL_MAX;
    int i, iTrain, iNearest = 0;

    for(iTrain=0; iTrain<nTrainFaces; iTrain++)
    {
        double distSq=0;

        for(i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
        {
            float d_i =
                projectedTestFace[i] -
                projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl[iTrain*nEigens + i];
            //distSq += d_i*d_i / eigenValMat->data.fl[i];  // Mahalanobis
            distSq += d_i*d_i; // Euclidean
        }

        if(distSq < leastDistSq)
        {
            leastDistSq = distSq;
            iNearest = iTrain;
        }
    }

    return iNearest;
}


//////////////////////////////////
// doPCA()
//
void doPCA()
{
    int i;
    CvTermCriteria calcLimit;
    CvSize faceImgSize;

    // set the number of eigenvalues to use
    nEigens = nTrainFaces-1;

    // allocate the eigenvector images
    faceImgSize.width  = faceImgArr[0]->width;
    faceImgSize.height = faceImgArr[0]->height;
    eigenVectArr = (IplImage**)cvAlloc(sizeof(IplImage*) * nEigens);
    for(i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
        eigenVectArr[i] = cvCreateImage(faceImgSize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

    // allocate the eigenvalue array
    eigenValMat = cvCreateMat( 1, nEigens, CV_32FC1 );

    // allocate the averaged image
    pAvgTrainImg = cvCreateImage(faceImgSize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

    // set the PCA termination criterion
    calcLimit = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, nEigens, 1);

    // compute average image, eigenvalues, and eigenvectors
    cvCalcEigenObjects(
        nTrainFaces,
        (void*)faceImgArr,
        (void*)eigenVectArr,
        CV_EIGOBJ_NO_CALLBACK,
        0,
        0,
        &calcLimit,
        pAvgTrainImg,
        eigenValMat->data.fl);

    cvNormalize(eigenValMat, eigenValMat, 1, 0, CV_L1, 0);
}


//////////////////////////////////
// loadFaceImgArray()
//
int loadFaceImgArray(char * filename)
{
    FILE * imgListFile = 0;
    char imgFilename[512];
    int iFace, nFaces=0;


    // open the input file
    if( !(imgListFile = fopen(filename, "r")) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can\'t open file %s\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    // count the number of faces
    while( fgets(imgFilename, 512, imgListFile) ) ++nFaces;
    rewind(imgListFile);

    // allocate the face-image array and person number matrix
    faceImgArr        = (IplImage **)cvAlloc( nFaces*sizeof(IplImage *) );
    personNumTruthMat = cvCreateMat( 1, nFaces, CV_32SC1 );

    // store the face images in an array
    for(iFace=0; iFace<nFaces; iFace++)
    {
        // read person number and name of image file
        fscanf(imgListFile,
            "%d %s", personNumTruthMat->data.i+iFace, imgFilename);

        // load the face image
        faceImgArr[iFace] = cvLoadImage(imgFilename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        if( !faceImgArr[iFace] )
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can\'t load image from %s\n", imgFilename);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(imgListFile);

    return nFaces;
}


//////////////////////////////////
// printUsage()
//
void printUsage()
{
    printf("Usage: eigenface <command>\n",
           "  Valid commands are\n"
           "    train\n"
           "    test\n");
}
```

1) The program exits with Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0) when I try to execute the program. Why is this so?

Need some help... Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I would make sure the data is really correctly loaded. Second make sure you are linking against the right OpenCV libraries. Some people had weird errors (similar to yours), because they did a Debug build while linking against the OpenCV build without debug symbols. Please have a look at the section on Release build configuration in my tutorial:

- http://bytefish.de/blog/opencv_visual_studio_and_libfacerec

I just wanted to let you know I am providing a face recognition library for OpenCV at:

- https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec

This one has Eigenfaces, Fisherfaces and Local Binary Patterns Histograms. And this: The library was also merged into OpenCV as of 2.4, so every OpenCV 2.4+ release ships with Eigenfaces, Fisherfaces and Local Binary Patterns Histograms. There's the demo application in the opencv/samples/cpp folder, that ships with any OpenCV installation:

- http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/entry/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/facerec_demo.cpp

I'll upload the documentation for OpenCV by the end of this week and update this post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I am trying the same thing.I think we need to provide command line arguments i.e train for learn and recognize for recognizing.We need to call the eigenfaces function using eigenface train or eigenface recognize.

Comment: I tried providing the arguments in visual studio but was not successful.I don't understand how to pass command line arguments in visual studio.If you get successful please reply me.

Comment: No... still unsuccessful....Asked in the yahoo group... still not able to solve this....